# I don't know how to solve this system of equations in $k_1,k_2$

Tags: analysis, systems-of-equations, stability-in-odes

This is the system I need to solve for $k_1, k_2$.

$k_1 = \lambda  y_n + \frac{\lambda h}{4}k_1 -\frac{\lambda h}{4}k_2  $

$    k_2 = \lambda  y_n + \frac{3\lambda h}{12}k_1  + \frac{5\lambda h}{12}k_2$

I'd also like to know if there's any symbolic calculator I can use to solve this type of problem since manually it becomes very tedious.

Comment: Go to WA: [`a=b*c+(b*d/4)*a-(b*d/4)*e,e=b*c+(3*b*d/12)*a+(5*b*d/12)*e solve for a,e`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%3Db*c%2B%28b*d%2F4%29*a-%28b*d%2F4%29*e%2Ce%3Db*c%2B%283*b*d%2F12%29*a%2B%285*b*d%2F12%29*e+solve+for+a%2Ce), where $a=k_1$, $e=k_2$, $b=\lambda$, $c=y_n$ and $d=h$.

Comment: Thanks, should've thought of doing it that way.

Comment: Mathematica will do it.  You need to tell it what to solve for, which I don't know how to do, but there is a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  @manooooh answer, the answer is:

[image]

Thanks everyone that contributed